# Exporting SVM classifiers from sklearn to Java codebase

Tags: java, scikit-learn, svm

I have used `sklearn` to train a set of SVM classifiers (mostly linear using `LinearSVM` but some of them are using the `SVC` class with rbf kernel) and I am pretty happy with the results. Now I need to export the classifiers in *production* into another codebase that uses Java. I am looking for possible libraries, that are published in maven, that can be easily incorporated in this new codebase.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Linear classifiers are easy: they have a `coef_` and an `intercept_`, described in the class docstrings. Those are regular NumPy arrays, so you can dump them to disk with standard NumPy functions.

```
>>> from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
>>> iris = load_iris()
>>> from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
>>> clf = LinearSVC().fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

Now let's dump this to a pseudo-file:

```
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> outfile = BytesIO()
>>> np.savetxt(outfile, clf.coef_)
>>> print(outfile.getvalue())
1.842426121444650788e-01 4.512319840786759295e-01 -8.079381916413134190e-01 -4.507115611351246720e-01
5.201335313639676022e-02 -8.941985347763323766e-01 4.052446671573840531e-01 -9.380586070674181709e-01
-8.506908158338851722e-01 -9.867329247779884627e-01 1.380997337625912147e+00 1.865393234038096981e+00
```

That's something you can parse from Java, right?

Now to get a score for the `k`'th class on a sample `x`, you need to evaluate

```
np.dot(x, clf.coef_[k]) + clf.intercept_[k]
# ==
(sum(x[i] * clf.coef_[k, i] for i in xrange(clf.coef_.shape[1]))
 + clf.intercept_[k])
```

which is also doable, I hope. The class with the highest score wins.

For kernel SVMs, the situation is more complicated because you need to replicate the [one-vs-one decision function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22831491/166749), as well as the kernels, in the Java code. The SVM model is stored on `SVC` objects in the attributes `support_vectors_` and `dual_coef_`.

Comment: I up-voted but this does not really answer my question :)

Comment: @nopper You mean you want a library? Then this question is off-topic.

Comment: The question is: I need to export a set of SVM classifier (sklearn) to Java with minimal effort. What libraries (java, possibly in maven) do you suggest?

Comment: Has anyone done the above with svms and made the effort public? Can't find anything on the web.

Comment: @CartesianTheater I maintain a project which ports learned models to a low level programming language like C, Java or JavaScript. But it's under active development. Anyway, you find it here: [https://github.com/nok/sklearn-porter](https://github.com/nok/sklearn-porter)

Comment: @DariusMorawiec Thanks, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to export SVM models in one framework and import them in another, but it could be helpful to understand which parameters describe your model - these are the support vectors selected by the SVM training mechanism, plus the kernel and (some) hyperparameters. I would save those into a file and then pickup any machine learning library in your target language and see if I could initialize SVM classifiers by feeding them with those parameters, instead of training them again.

Comment: I guess that for linear classifiers should be easy since they expose just a set of coefficients, but probably it will be more complicated for non-linear ones. Anyway the question was about the best Java library for this scope that also is published in maven? I can afford to retrain the entire set classifiers if the results are going to be the same.

Comment: Yea I don't know that, was just trying to suggest that in your search for a library, "import" function might not be a crucial factor (also SO is a bit antagonistic to "help me choose a library" questions - see that close vote (not mine) - and I wanted to highlight there's a more inteeresting aspect to your question)

Comment: Yes I understood your point. Indeed before creating this specific question I looked for similar question. At the end I find out that there are people precisely looking for exporting sklearn classifiers (without retraining) to Java codebase, such as this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511968/python-scikit-learn-exporting-trained-classifier). Therefore I decided to loosen the requirements and accept the possibility of completely retraining my models ;)